# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a strange problem. I have an editor in React which returns the following:

```
    const [isFullscreenMode, setIsFullscreenMode] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div
            id="editor-container"
            className={`mw-textarea ${
                isFullscreenMode ? "mw-editor--fullscreen" : ""
            }`}
        >
            <MenuBar
                editor={editor as Editor}
                isCodeViewMode={isCodeViewMode}
                setIsCodeViewMode={setIsCodeViewMode}
                isFullscreenMode={isFullscreenMode}
                setIsFullscreenMode={setIsFullscreenMode}
            />

            <div
                id="editor-content"
                className={`s-prose ProseMirror ${!isCodeViewMode ? "" : "d-none"}`}
            >
                <EditorContent editor={editor} />
            </div>

            {isCodeViewMode && (
                <div
                    id="codemirror"
                    className={`mw-editor__codemirror ${isCodeViewMode ? "" : "d-none"}`}
                >
                    <textarea ref={cmTextAreaRef}></textarea>
                </div>
            )}

            {!isCodeViewMode && !isFullscreenMode && (
                <div>Empty div...</div>
            )}

        </div>
    );
```

So I have a state `isFullscreenMode` which controls whether to render or not the currently empty div with text `Empty div...`. This state is managed from inside `MenuBar` nside `FullscreenButton` as follows:

```
export const FullscreenButton = ({
    editor,
    isFullscreenMode,
    setIsFullscreenMode,
}: Props) => {
    return (
        <MenuButton
            icon={!isFullscreenMode ? <ScreenFullIcon /> : <ScreenNormalIcon />}
            command={() => {
                setIsFullscreenMode(!isFullscreenMode);
                return true; //editor.commands.focus();
            }}
            active={isFullscreenMode}
            tooltip={{
                content: <TooltipContent content="Fullscreen" />,
            }}
        />
    );
};
```

When I click it, the div correctly disappers and I'm in the fullscreen mode. BUT when I want to escape fullscreen mode, I've got an error:

[image]

What is going on?